# I have a json file and I want to create Hive external table over it but with more descriptive field names

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a JSON file and I want to create Hive external table over it but with more descriptive field names.Basically, I want to map the less descriptive field names present in json file to more descriptive fields in Hive external table.

```
e.g.
{"field1":"data1","field2":100}
```

Hive Table:

```
Create External Table my_table (Name  string, Id  int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde'
LOCATION '/path-to/my_table/';
```

Where Name points to field1 and Id points to field2.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this SerDe that allows custom mappings between the JSON data and the hive columns: https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

See in particular this part: https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#mapping-hive-keywords

so, in your case, you'd need to do something like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table(name STRING, id, INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
   "mapping.name" = "field1",
   "mapping.id" = "field2" ) 
LOCATION '/path-to/my_table/'
```

Note that hive column names are case insensitive, while JSON attributes
are case sensitive.